# Speed of divergence at infinity of inverse cdf

Tags: calculus, probability, limits, probability-distributions, cumulative-distribution-functions

Consider two random variables with cdf F and G and of bounded support. I noted that if $F^{-1}(G(x))/x$ increases, we have that $F^{-1}(G(x))/x\le F^{-1}(G(x))/1=1$. My question is, can the bounded support hypothesis be removed, perhaps with some additional structure on $G$? For example if $G$ is geometric (i.e. $1-q^x$) and the density of $F$ is decreasing. I was not successful in proving it even in such a simple scenario. Thanks for any help.

Comment: $n(1-F(n))$ does not vanish if for example $F(n)=1-\frac1n$ or $F(n)=1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$

Comment: and then you completely changed the question

Comment: it needs to be the cdf of an integrable r.v. as I stated before the rewrite. Apologies anyway, I think the question was ill posed, I wrote it again to be closer to the exercise I was trying to solve.